# Implement muti-qubit controlled gate with 2 Z/X gates

Tags: qiskit, programming, quantum-gate, ibm-q-experience

[This paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/326978036_Solving_Sudoku_game_using_a_hybrid_classical-quantum_algorithm) simulates duality mode to solve sudoku puzzles. The last diagram in the paper (shown below) illustrates multi-qubit controlled gates with two Z/X gates. I wonder if Qiskit can directly implement these gates.

[image]

Comment: The two Z gates in a single circuit is just a shorthand for two separate Z gates, both with the same set of controls.  Likewise for the X Gate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @FrankYellin mentioned in the comments, this is theoretically equivalent to two `MCXGate` applied successively (up to some `HGate` for the $Z$ version).

However, you shouldn't worry about this, a framework's goal is to let it deal with low-level implementation, while you should care about what operation you want to perform. Fundamentally, what you're looking for is a multi-controlled $XX$ gate.

Qiskit has an `RXXGate`, but this will include an unwanted relative phase. You can create the $XX$ gate like this:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit

circ = QuantumCircuit(2)
circ.x([0, 1])
xx_gate = circ.to_gate(label="XXGate")
```

Now that we have our $XX$ gate, we can control it out of other qubits as desired, like so:

```
from qiskit import QuantumRegister

# Be careful about Qiskit's little-endian convention
controlled_xx_gate = xx_gate.control(7, "MCXXGate", "0000100")

alpha = QuantumRegister(4, "alpha")
beta = QuantumRegister(4, "beta")
gamma = QuantumRegister(4, "gamma")

circ = QuantumCircuit(alpha, beta, gamma)
circ.h([alpha[-1], beta[-1], gamma[-1]])

# Using HXH = Z
circ.h([beta[0], gamma[0]])
# Be careful about Qiskit's little-endian convention
circ.append(controlled_xx_gate, [*alpha[:-1], beta[1], beta[-1], gamma[1], gamma[-1], beta[0], gamma[0]])
circ.h([beta[0], gamma[0]])

# Be careful about Qiskit's little-endian convention
circ.append(controlled_xx_gate, [*alpha[:-1], beta[1], beta[-1], gamma[1], gamma[-1], beta[0], gamma[0]])
```

The resulting circuit looks like this:

[image]

Comment: What does "*" do in the last line of code? Which code creates anti-controlled gate?

Comment: @Yili `*alpha[:-1]` is a shorthand for `alpha[0], alpha[1], alpha[2]`. More generally, `*my_list` "unwraps" the list. The controls of the gate are defined via the string `"0000100"`, which means that the gate will be applied if the first 4 qubits are 0, the fifth one 1 and the last ones 0. Note that because of Qiskit's convention to use little-endian, this has to be read from bottom to top wire-wise.

Comment: Which part of codes do you specify which wire(s) to append xx_gate within the gate "MCXXGate"?

Comment: @Yili This one: `controlled_xx_gate = xx_gate.control(7, "MCXXGate", "0000100")`. This code transforms the `xx_gate` to a controlled version of it, which I labelled `MCXXGate`, controlled by the string `"0000100"`. The convention in Qiskit when creating such a gate is that the first inputs are the controls, and the last ones the inputs to the original gate, which is why, when applying it, we pass `beta[0]` and `gamma[0]` as the last parameters: these are the registers on which we wish to apply the $XX$ gate